# RTE in own backend module based on Extbase and Fluid

Tags: typo3

for a complex structure of a domain model (lots of fields and some relations) it´s planned to write an own backend module to be more flexible according to the structure and usability of that module. And there are some dependencies of some fields which I think I cannot make it just via TCA resp. FlexForms. So one thing I hope someone has done that before: If I build an own BE module with extbase and Fluid etc. and have forms with input fields or better textfields: 
How can I add an RTE to such a field? Is that possible? I´ve read the TYPO3 Extbase book, but the example there do not contain a RTE.

Answer (score 0):

in case you would like to use the same RTE as TYPO3 it is quite difficult to add all required scripts including the configuration of RTE to a field and I can't help you with that.

But I would like to remember you that in TYPO3 8 LTS the ckeditor becomes the new TYPO3 editor. So you may look forward to directly use it in your backend module or check out the docs of 8 LTS regarding the usage of it on own fields (if any docs exists yet).

http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: Thanks Paul for the advice. This could be an idea. I´ll first go the way using the Flexforms now. But I´ll keep in mind ckeditor, which also looks promising. Thx (and sorry for the late reply).