# How to add CKEditor RTE to typo3 Backend Module with the API?

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, fluid, extbase

This question is similar to that one: [RTE in own backend module based on Extbase and Fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721754/rte-in-own-backend-module-based-on-extbase-and-fluid)
 but not the same, so i created a new question.

---

I create a comment-extension for typo3 Version 8.7.7

I have added a RTE Editor (CKEditor) to a textarea field in my BackendModule.

Therefore i have the following TCA in my comment-model:

```tca
'text' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:rmcomment/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_rmcomment_domain_model_comment.text',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'text',
        'enableRichtext' => true,
        'richtextConfiguration' => 'minimal',
        'fieldControl' => [
            'fullScreenRichtext' => [
                'disabled' => false,
            ],
        ],
        'cols' => 40,
        'rows' => 15,
        'eval' => 'trim,required',
    ],
],
```

The backend template looks like this:

```html
<f:form action="create" name="newComment" object="{newComment}" arguments="{author:beuser.username, email:beuser.email}">

    <strong>Eingeloggt als: {beuser.realname} (Username: {beuser.username}) (Email: {beuser.email})</strong><br>

    <label for="commentEmailCheckbox">Öffentliche E-Mail:</label>
        <f:form.checkbox id="commentEmailCheckbox" property="mailPublic" value="1" />
    <br><br>

    <label for="commentText" class="text{rm:hasError(property:'text',then:' text-danger')}">
        <f:translate key="tx_rmcomment_domain_model_comment.text" />
        <span class="small">( <f:translate key="tx_rmcomment_domain_model_comment.required" /> )</span>
    </label><br>
        <f:form.textarea id="commentText" property="text" cols="120" rows="6" /><br>

    <f:form.submit value="{f:translate(key:'tx_rmcomment_domain_model_comment.saveComment')}" class="btn btn-default" />
</f:form>
```

---

**Is there a better way to make that RTE working for my Backend-Module without "dirty javascript" (**my answer**) inside my fluid-template?**

**EDIT**

I think this is the only solution, so i move the working part to an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Under the new form i add this javascript:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/typo3conf/ext/rmcomment/Resources/Public/Backend/RTE/ckcomment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My ckcomment.js looks like this:

```js
// Configure New Comment CKEditor-Form
CKEDITOR.config.customConfig = '/typo3conf/ext/rmcomment/Resources/Public/Backend/RTE/backendRTEconfig.js';
CKEDITOR.replace( 'commentText' );
$('.text').click(function(){
    CKEDITOR.instances.commentText.focus();
});
```

And the backendRTEconfig.js has this content:

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Blockquote', ] },
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source' ] },
    ];
};
```

Now i got a CKEditor for my Backend Module with customized editor-buttons. Until now it's the only way i found.

In another extension my **custom content elements** don't have to load the **ckeditor "library"** nor my **configuration-javascript**. There I only had to add the TCA: `'richtextConfiguration' => 'minimal'`

If someone know how to activate ckeditor without the javascirpt "loader" in my template, let me know.

Comment: Not native, but I have an idea... if I make a TypoScript Condition, which checks isBackend then I possibly could use includeJs or includeJsFooter... but not tested atm...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up loading CKEditor from the JavaScript Directory of the extension. Pretty unnecessary, but it works...

Comment: like me, or did you found another way?

Comment: No, not really, sorry... I wish I had... ;)